# Get time_t from microseconds in the past

Tags: c++11

Working on a c++ 11 function that returns a string from an epoch timestamp with millisecond resolution. Doing this with the current date seems straight forward:

```
auto currentTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now( );
const time_t time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t( currentTime );
```

However, I'm having a hard time finding out to initialize without `now()` and instead using a timestamp from the past. Trying to do this using std library, but can't quite see how to initialize the time_point using a past timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the `std::chrono::duration` class. Below is an example.

```
unsigned long noOfClockTicks = 10111111111; // Mar 16 10:31:59 2018
std::chrono::duration<unsigned long> duration(noOfClockTicks);
system_clock::time_point pastTime(duration);
```

Adjust `noOfClockTicks` to get the correct value you want or you can even calculate it from `std::chrono::system_clock::now()`.